# Mysql Exception Cannot Connect to any of the specified hosts - WPF only

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, connection

I know similiar issues have been solved here, but this is kind o weird...

When I try to connect to remote Mysql using Connector/NET in WPF, I get an XAMLParseException. The inner exception says it could not connect to any of the specified hosts. 
However, when I tried it using WinForms instead of WPF, it worked fine, so I believe the connection string, server settings and the MySQL assemblies work. So the problem will probably be in the XAML. This is the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="_min_t1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Label" Height="58" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,35,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" />
</Grid>
```

but that`s exactly what VS generated for a new project...

Any ideas?

Comment: XAML is used for creating UI so it won't affect how you connect to MySQL. If you can connect from your WinForms app, then the connection is set up properly there. Post the stack trace of the exception you are getting.

Comment: here is the stack trace:

Comment: or the top of it...
   `at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)`

Comment: OK, it probably wont have anything to do with the xaml, I moved connecting to an event and XAML exception was gone, but it still cannot conect to any of the hosts - the connection string: `"Server=109.74.158.75;Uid=....;Pwd=....;Database=ks;pooling=false"` and the whole code I would like to run is:
            `MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            label1.Content = conn.State.ToString();
            conn.Close();`

Comment: Just got it working, I had wrong structure in App.config ( the backtrace showed it clearly, just had to learn to use the debugger :] ), sorry for bothering you...